# jQuery: how to find first visible input/select/textarea excluding buttons?

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-selectors

I tried

```
$(":input:not(input[type=button],input[type=submit],button):visible:first")
```

but it doesn't find anything.

What is my mistake?

UPD: I execute this on $(document).load()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
  var aspForm  = $("form#aspnetForm");
  var firstInput = $(":input:not(input[type=button],input[type=submit],button):visible:first", aspForm);
  firstInput.focus();
});
</script>
```

and in the debug I can see that firstInput is empty.

UPD2:
I'm in ASP.NET page running under Sharepoint.

I've found so far that for some elements it does find them (for fixed ones) and for some don't. :(

Comment: Try "input" instead of ":input"?

Comment: Should work fine. Your problem lies somewhere else. Aren't you executing this *before* the `$(document)` is `ready()`?

Comment: Do you have a specific html to search on?

Comment: Maybe the first input is of `type="hidden"`? Rightclick page and view source. The generated HTML matters as well. Without it and an proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), it's shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Why not just target the ones you want ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VU3vg/))?

```
$('form').find('input[type=text],textarea,select').filter(':visible:first');
```

**Edit**

Or use jQuery [:input](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector to filter form descendants.

```
$('form').find('*').filter(':input:visible:first');
```

Comment: Checkbox? Radio? Password? Not to mention the lot of new HTML5 input types.

Comment: @BalusC $('form').find(':input').filter(':visible:first')

Comment: While this works to some degree, it does ignore the tabindex attribute.

Comment: Small nitpick but useful addition: instead of ':visible:first', ':visible:enabled:first' will be a much better filter because the top element could be disabled in some cases and the focus can't shift there.

Comment: @PrahladYeri Perhaps also exclude readonly `':input:visible:enabled:not([readonly]):first'`

Answer (score 13):

The JQuery code is fine. You must execute in the ready handler not in the window load event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  var aspForm  = $("form#aspnetForm");
  var firstInput = $(":input:not(input[type=button],input[type=submit],button):visible:first", aspForm);
  firstInput.focus();
});
</script>
```

**Update**

I tried with the example of Karim79(thanks for the example) and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2sMfU/

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. I'm going to go shoot myself now. I hate myself. I could have spent the last hour not messing with working code. I could have fed my dogs, cleaned my kitchen. There are many things I could have achieved. Now all I have is pain. Goodbye, forever....And yes, I *should* have listened.

Comment: @karim: rofl. You're welcome :) Btw: I already bathed my kids, brought them in bed, fed the dogs and cats and took myself a coca cola ;)

Answer (score 7):

This is my summary of the above and works perfectly for me.  Thanks for the info!

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var firstInput = $('form').find('input[type=text],input[type=password],input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox],textarea,select').filter(':visible:first');
        if (firstInput != null) {
            firstInput.focus();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an improvement over @Mottie's answer because as of jQuery 1.5.2 `:text` selects `input` elements that have no specified `type` attribute (in which case `type="text"` is implied):

```
$('form').find(':text,textarea,select').filter(':visible:first')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. The code should be easy enough to follow but here is the idea:

- get all inputs, selects, and textareas
- filter out all buttons and hidden fields
- filter to only enabled, visible fields
- select the first one
- focus the selected field

The code:

```
function focusFirst(parent) {
    $(parent).find('input, textarea, select')
        .not('input[type=hidden],input[type=button],input[type=submit],input[type=reset],input[type=image],button')
        .filter(':enabled:visible:first')
        .focus();
}
```

Then simply call focusFirst with your parent element or selector.

Selector:

```
focusFirst('form#aspnetForm');
```

Element:

```
var el = $('form#aspnetForm');
focusFirst(el);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try below code...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').find('input[type=text],textarea,select').filter(':visible:first').focus();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
    
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```