# OnRowEditing Edit Textbox Focus

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, gridview

What I'm trying to do is, upon the GridView_OnRowEditing event, I want to focus on the textbox that appears in the cell I am editing. From there I will trigger a javascript keyboard, but I need to focus on the textbox first before I can do anything.

Here is my current code:

```
protected void GridView_OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = GridView.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
        var gridText = (TextBox) row.Cells[5].Controls[0];
        gridText.Focus();
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Here's my GridView mark up. I'm not manually setting a textbox. If there is anyway to retrieve an ID of the cell that is converted to the textbox on RowEditing event, please let me know. Thank you.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataKeyNames="RollNumber" DataSourceID="WoSource" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
        OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" AllowSorting="true" Visible="True" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="GridView1_OnRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_OnRowCancelingEdit" Width="100%">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkOrderNo" HeaderText="WorkOrderNo" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="WorkOrderNo" Visible="False"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RollNumber" HeaderText="RollNumber" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="RollNumber" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ModelNumber" HeaderText="ModelNumber" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ModelNumber" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="QtyGood" HeaderText="QtyGood" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="QtyGood" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="QtyRun" HeaderText="QtyRun" SortExpression="QtyRun"><ControlStyle Width="100%" Height="100%" Font-Size="36px"></ControlStyle></asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Unless there's been a recent serious change in ASP.Net, I'm pretty sure you cannot execute C# code on the client. Aka as soon as you start editing the gridview, it would either reload (because you've hooked up a server event), or it would do nothing. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Please read [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1906471.aspx?set+focus+on+gridview+template+textbox). Should give you some clue.

Comment: This needs more explanation. Right now it's unclear to me what you want and what you are using. Is this a web app? If so Bjarke is right, you won't be able to do it on server side. Use javascript events to do it.

Comment: I see. @okisinch how would I go about getting the ID of the textbox that appears? I do not have an ItemTemplate TextBox set up. I'm just focusing on the Cell that converts to a TextBox when Edit is clicked. If I can get the ID, I think it wouldn't be as hard to set up the javascript events.

Comment: Well in javascript/jquery when you click edit (onClick event) you could get the table row where you clicked edit and select the first <input> texbox in that table row. Please provide more info (more code, the html part of the grid) and if not me surely someone else will be able to help.

Comment: @okisinch i added the asp markup for the gridview. i understand what you're saying script-wise. however, is it possible to just look for the first textbox in that row? or does it have to be by an ID? In this case, i don't think the cells that are converted to textbox have one. If i manually set an ItemTemplate textbox, it could get the ID, but in this situation, I can't do that.

Comment: it is possible to find the first. Here is the jquery documentation with example http://api.jquery.com/first/ and some more examples https://blog.logentries.com/2012/09/focus-on-the-first-input-element-in-jquery/ and some more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823471/jquery-how-to-find-first-visible-input-select-textarea-excluding-buttons

Comment: @okisinch Hey for that blog.logentries example, can you insert a GridView.ID in place of the '#form-id'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from @okisinch I discovered I could do this:

```
        $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> :input:enabled:visible:first').focus();
        $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> :input:enabled:visible:first').select();
```

The benefit of this is that I wouldn't need to find an textbox ID to be able to focus.

This [link](https://blog.logentries.com/2012/09/focus-on-the-first-input-element-in-jquery/) was the resource that helped me.

**Edit:** Discovered this code works as well. Note that the #insideContainer is a jquery keyboard that was implemented. I figured I would add the triggering that I did.

```
    $(function () {
        if ($('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> :input:enabled:visible:first').val()) {
            $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> :input:enabled:visible:first').focus();
            $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> :input:enabled:visible:first').select();
            $('#insideContainer').show();
        } else {
            $('#insideContainer').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm glad you have found a solution to your problem. Sorry for not responding, I was off the grid for the weekend.

Comment: if i wanted to do it in the nested grid.any lead