# JQuery how to serach visible elements from a set of objects stored in a variable

Tags: jquery

Lest's say i have a set of elements stored in a variable like this:

```
 var elements = $('.someClass');
```

Then some time later i need to dertermine all visible elements in my variable.
So how can i achieve this? Is there a buildin selection from jquery for this like:

```
var visible = $(':visible', elements); // just an example!
```

Some suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

I made a fiddle for a better understanding:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/4tyrb42o/)

My conclusion:

**.filter(..)** works perfectly cause is searchs directly on the given elements.

**.find(..)** and **$(':visible', elements)** looks for visible child-elements in the given elements.

Comment: What you have in your second block (using the contextual selector) should work fine. You could also use `find()`. Is there an issue with it?

Comment: `elements.filter(':visible')`?!  It is not clear imho if you are looking to filter out matched set or descendants from matched set

Comment: I may miss something but my exampel isn't working. This will always return 0 elements, even there are some visible!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how to find first visible input/select/textarea excluding buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823471/jquery-how-to-find-first-visible-input-select-textarea-excluding-buttons)

Comment: You should provide concrete sample regarding your issue as a jsFiddle and better explain what you are looking for.

Comment: @A.Wolff I thought to say 'all visible elements in my variable' was clear enought. Will aske more specifically next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
var filterElements = elements.filter(':visible');
```

Comment: works perfectly ... i forgot to think about the .filter function. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

```
var visible = elements.find(":visible");
```

its works