# how to find first input/select in jquery

Tags: jquery

I used the following line to do so, but it fails when a select comes on the form. It lefts select and then it stops working even for inputs.

```
var $ele = $("select,input[type='text'],input[type='password']:visible[required]").filter(function () 
    { return this.value.trim() == '' || this.value.trim().indexOf('--') != -1 ;
     }).eq(0);
```

Comment: `$('form').find('input[type=text]:first,select:first')` or `$('form').find('input[type=text],select').first()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may looking for below code.

```
$('form').find('input[type=text],select').filter(':visible:first')
```

Comment: can i use filter multiple times as i need to check some conditions like :-  return this.value.trim() == '' || this.value.trim().indexOf('--') != -1

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('form').find('input[type=text],select').filter(':visible:first')
```

[(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823471/jquery-how-to-find-first-visible-input-select-textarea-excluding-buttons)

Comment: I modified my function but still not working, new function :--          var $ele = $("select,input[type='text'],input[type='password']").filter(":visible[required]").filter(function () { return this.value.trim() == '' || this.value.trim().indexOf('--') != -1 || this.value.trim().indexOf('Select') != -1; }).eq(0);

Comment: Hmm, try replacing `:visible[required]` with `:visible:required:`.