# Is there any way to edit a URL to embed a form entry?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I know it is possible to embed form values into the URL as parameters if the form has an ID assigned to it. But what if it does not have an ID?

For example the "Search" field in this page:

http://au.autodesk.com/speaker-resource-center/call-for-proposals/voting

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search " class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty search-box" ng-model="search.$" ng-change="updateButtons()">
```

Comment: So how do you do when the form has an id? ... show that code please

Comment: Nothing on that link seems to affect the URL. What exactly are you trying to do? Auto-fill an input tag on loading a page?

Comment: something like this. when you open this link it already shows the result from google, https://www.google.com/search?q=load&oq=load&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j69i59l2.543j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I think that is because Google's `/search` URL takes a query (`/search?q=..........`) as a parameter and fills the field with that parameter. If you are designing your own website, you can do this in a similar way. On someone else's website though, you'll need to run a TamperMonkey script or use Selenium or something to do this automatically, unless the site designer has designed similar functionality into their website. I wouldn't recommend Pen Testing someone else's website or spamming it with automated scripts though...

Answer (score 0):

> I know it is possible to embed form values into the URL as parameters if the form has an ID assigned to it.

That is not true.

Server-side (and occasionally client-side) code on a page may read the query string as a means to set default values for form controls (typically so that a form can be corrected and resubmitted if there were errors in the previous attempt).

In these cases, the `name` attributes will usually map onto the query string (because the form will generate the query string from the name attributes). Often an input will be given an `id` that is the same as its `name`.

It is entirely under the control of the site's authors.

There is no way to set values of inputs on another site without the other side providing a mechanism to allow you to do that.

Comment: since I am really a rookie, is it possible to add a parameter to the URL  I posted so that when it pops up the "search" field has a value?

Comment: @DevRookie — I don't know. I don't work for autodesk and I'm not going to start running pen tests on their site.

Answer (score -1):

There's a few different ways to do that. Looking at that HTML, it's the first text-type input inside the div, so the first method that comes to mind is this:

You could pull out the div (using the class "search-area") and then target the first text input box within that div. I don't know whether you're using jQuery or native JS or exactly what language/library/framework you're using.

JQuery would be something like:

```
var inputElement = $(".search-area")[0].first()
```

This SO answer may help:

[jQuery: how to find first visible input/select/textarea excluding buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823471/jquery-how-to-find-first-visible-input-select-textarea-excluding-buttons)

Edited to add: Answer is targetting the input element. As the answer from someone else mentions.. You can't actually do what you're wanting to do with the URL.

Edited again. Misread the question. I'll leave this here in case someone else needs to know how to target an input field that doesn't have an ID. Alternatively, I have no problems if someone wants to delete this answer.