# How to get a radio button value of one form when multiple forms are dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a widget that creates a wizard (steps).

Each step has a form and can contain radio buttons. The variable `formname` contains the name of the current form. How can I get the value of a radio button clicked inside that form? Not all forms will have radio buttons.

This is an example of my html layout:

```
<div id="step-0" class="">
  <form id="step_0_form" method="post">
    <input type="number" class="formateninput form-control" name="aantal" value="1" min="1">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="step-1" class="">
  <form id="step_1_form" method="post">
    <input type="number" class="formateninput form-control" name="hoogte" value="100" min="60">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="step-2" class="">
  <form id="step_2_form" method="post">
      <input type="radio" id="Hout" name="Materiaal" value="Hout" >
      <input type="radio" id="Debond" name="Materiaal" value="Debond">
  </form>
</div>
```

And this is my jquery code at the moment:

```
var ajaxInvoke = false;
$("#smartwizard").on("leaveStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection) {

  if(ajaxInvoke == false){
    ajaxInvoke = true;

    var form_data = $("#step_"+ stepNumber +"_form").serialize();

    var formname = $("#step_"+ stepNumber +"_form");

    $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:"catalog/calcdiv.php",
      data:form_data,
      success:function(data){
         // indicate the ajax has been done, release the next step
         $("#smartwizard").smartWizard("next");
         ajaxInvoke = false;
      }
    });
    // Return false to cancel the `leaveStep` event
    return false;
  }
});
```

I tried the following:

```
var ajaxInvoke = false;
$("#smartwizard").on("leaveStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection) {

  if(ajaxInvoke == false){
    ajaxInvoke = true;

    var form_data = $("#step_"+ stepNumber +"_form").serialize();

    var formname = $("#step_"+ stepNumber +"_form");

    $(formname).on("change" "input[type=radio]:checked", function(e){
      var val = $(this).val();
      console.log(val);
    });

    $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:"catalog/calcdiv.php",
      data:form_data,
      success:function(data){
         // indicate the ajax has been done, release the next step
         $("#smartwizard").smartWizard("next");
         ajaxInvoke = false;
      }
    });
    // Return false to cancel the `leaveStep` event
    return false;
  }
});
```

But this doesn't show anything in my console. How can I get the value of the radio button clicked on the current step in the currently opened form? `$("#step_"+ stepNumber +"_form");` is the corresponding form id.

Comment: Will there be a time where you need to check the value of a radio button from a different form?

Comment: **[This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823471/jquery-how-to-find-first-visible-input-select-textarea-excluding-buttons)**. Just try to get the value of the radio button which is visible.

Comment: @Chillin' Yea when I go to the next step (every step contains a form, so the next form) and it has radio buttons I also need to get the value from that when a radio button is clicked there.

Comment: I dont actually think it matters what form you're on, does it? If you're doing it for validation reasons at the end, then just validate ALL fields on submit.
With that being said, you can just get the value of a radio button by using `$("input[name=Materiaal]:checked").val()`. This gets the value of a checkbox with the name Materiaal that is checked

Comment: @Chillin' Yes I know but the radio buttons are created dynamically so they won't all have the same name in each form. The next radio button names in another form could be another name. So I just need the value of the current checked radio button in the currently opened form, which is `$("#step_"+ stepNumber +"_form")`

Comment: Will/could a form section have more than one radio button? If not, target THE radio button by doing `$('#form-name input:radio:checked').val();`, which gets the radio button within a div of id `form-name`